# Get text values from Global picklist in CRM Online 2013?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

How can I extract values from Global picklist in crm 2013? I update some text fields based on the value of the option set. Usually in local option set we can use the following code to update the fields based on the value of option set.

```
var value = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_optionset").getText();
if(value=="ABC"){
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_field1").setValue("Value");
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_field2").setValue("Some Value");
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_field3").setValue("Some Other Value");
 }
```

But this does not seem to work if I am using a global option set. Is there another way of handling them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From JavaScript there is no difference how to get the text between a local and a global optionset.

The syntax is the one you already know:

```
var value = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_optionset").getText();
```

If you want a library to manage the optionsets you can check this one I wrote:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/OptionSet-JavaScript-76af41f5

Comment: how to use this library

Comment: there is also the sample in the link